# Main method not found even if I've declared it

Tags: java

I want to create a simple java class, with a main method, but when I compile my code, I get this error message :

> Error: Main method not found in class errors.TestErrors, please define
>   the main method as:    public static void main(String[] args)

This is the source code :

```
package errors;

public class TestErrors {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Why I'm seeing this error, as you can notice I've alreader declared the main method !

Comment: How are you running the compilation, `javac`?

Comment: Looks like you've declared a `String` class among your classes.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That's crazy insight. NJ.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis once I had a problem using `Class` and it was because I carelessly created a `class Class` for testing purposes. Similar can happen with `String` and other. To prove this, try using the full name of `String` class, this means, change your `main` method to receive a `java.lang.String[] args` argument .

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm using Eclipse

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No this is the only class I'v declared so far

Comment: @user2874861 Don't forget to save/build your program.

Comment: @user Post the output of the command `javap -s errors.TestErrors`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As said in my comments, looks like you've declared a `String` class among your own classes. To prove this, I've created a basic example:

```
class String {
}

public class CarelessMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("won't get printed");
    }
    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
        System.out.println("worked");
    }
}
```

If you execute this code, it will print `"worked"` in the console. If you comment the second `main` method, the application will throw an error with this message (similar for your environment):

> Error: Main method not found in class edu.home.poc.component.CarelessMain, please define the main method as:
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args)
> ```

Comment: @user2874861 Most certainly you didn't compile your code after the change.

Comment: @user2874861 did this answer really helped you to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

This usually happens if ur complete project isnotconfigured correctly
or one of your class in project has still some errors
in such cases IDE will prompt stating the same that project contains some error
and you still proceed (ie run your class)
as project has some bugs new classes will not be created and IDE will run
the class which was available previously

to make sure this is ur case u can add new class in your project and try to run it and if ur getting no such class exist then there its is a perfect evidence

Answer (score 2):

Just check your java file, it has not been saved. Please save all java files before compiling.

Comment: Someone gave the solution before you, I don't find your answer to be appropriate.

Comment: well this answer help me for my situation , I though no need save it because it will happen automatically .

Answer (score 0):

If the answers above are not working for you: **make sure "main" is not capitalized in your method definition.**

OK: 
`public static void main(String[] args)`

ERROR:
`public static void Main(String[] args)`

Though the error message makes the required syntax for the main method clear, incorrect caps can be hard to spot. It took me ~30 minutes of troubleshooting to find this typo today. This was clearly not an issue for the OP, but is another easy/likely way to produce the same error message, and this answer may help other users.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue just now. This error came up because the JRE file that i switched out didn't had the full library. After I corrected/added the right JRE system library the problem went away.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the class name (which you are trying to run)->Run As->Run Configurations->Under Main Class Tab

Write your main class name and hit on Run.

Answer (score -1):

Try commenting the first line.

```
//package errors;
```