# what is the solution to this error, this program is showing main method not found but i have defined one ? code is given below

Tags: java

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.*;
public class MyBarbeque {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/Barbecue", "root", "");
            CallableStatement cs;
            cs = conn.prepareCall("{call showBarbeque}");
            ResultSet rest = cs.executeQuery();
            while (rest.next()) {
                System.out.println(rest.getString("bType") + "  " + rest.getString("bPrice"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the error that you get?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339088/main-method-not-found-even-if-ive-declared-it

Comment: Have you possibly removed a package declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the method singnature to

```
 public static void main(java.lang.String[] args){}
```

adding package name to string.You might have created your own `String` class on your folder which is causing the confusion for jvm to access your main method.

Comment: @Makoto I could only see the post up to the code block for some reason.  Deleting comment.

Comment: this is the error i am getting                                                                                                           Error: Main method not found in class MyBarbeque, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)

Comment: @GovindaBhattar how are you running the code thorough IDE or cmd?

Comment: do you have any other classes on the same package?

Comment: no only this class is present

Comment: try creating and running new class