# Error: Main method not found in class newpackage.Myclass, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: eclipse, automation, cucumber

Trace:

> Error: Main method not found in class newpackage.Myclass, please
>   define the main methods: public static void main(String[] args) or a
>   JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application.

MyClass.java

```
package newpackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//import javafx.application.*;
public class Myclass {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users \\karokiaswamy\\Documents\\Selenium_installation\\geckodriver-v0.15.0-win64)\\geckodriver.exe");
           WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
           driver.get("http://Application URL");
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='siteLoginTab']/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input")).sendKeys("USER NAME");
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='siteLoginTab']/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys("Password");
           driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='siteLoginTab]/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/input")).click();
           driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='siteLoginTab']/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(" ");
           driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='siteMain']/div[1]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/input")).click();
           driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='siteMain']/div[1]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/input")).click();
   }
}
```

Comment: Right click on the project -> Run As -> Run Configuration -> Add the main class. Give a try!

Comment: checl this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339088/main-method-not-found-even-if-ive-declared-it it may help you!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Main method not found even if I've declared it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339088/main-method-not-found-even-if-ive-declared-it)