# Getting error in eclipse as: Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.String to abcd.String

Tags: arrays, string, selenium-webdriver

```
package abcd;


public class Arraymethods {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] array1={10,20,30,40,50};
        String array2 []={"Selenium", "UFT", "RFT", "SilkTest"};


        //length method
        System.out.println(array1.length);

        //toString method

        String str= Arrays.toString(array2);
        System.out.println(str);
        String x=Arrays.toString(array1);
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(x);

        //Contains method
        boolean a= Arrays.asList(array2).contains("RFT");
        boolean b= Arrays.asList(array2).contains("Java");
        boolean c= Arrays.asList(array2).contains("UFT");
        System.out.println(a);//true
        System.out.println(b);//false
        System.out.println(c);//true


    }
```

I have used the same code without any errors, but all of a sudden I'm seeing error

Comment: what line is it complaining about?

Comment: Please provide the complete exception trace

Comment: Error: Main method not found in class abcd.Arraymethods, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: at the lines: 8,16, 18 it is showing the error: type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.String to abcd.String

Comment: I have reinstalled my eclipse ....it is working fine now without any errors....Thank You...........

Answer (score -1):

Please provide the stack trace.
Your code executes, and gives the below output.

```
5
[Selenium, UFT, RFT, SilkTest]
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
true
false
true
```

Comment: My only difference was I named the package and class differently, and it had to import java.util.arrays

Comment: Error: Main method not found in class abcd.Arraymethods, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: at the lines: 8,16, 18 it is showing the error: type mismatch: cannot convert from java.lang.String to abcd.String

Comment: I have reinstalled my eclipse ....it is working fine now without any errors....Thank You............

Comment: package abcd;

public abstract class Bikes {
 public void handle(){
 System.out.println("Bikes have handle");
 }

 public void seat(){
  System.out.println("Bikes have seats");
  }
 
 public abstract void engine();
  
 public abstract void wheels(); 
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 //Bikes obj = new Bikes(); - we cannot use object for abstract class
  
 
  Herobikes xyz= new Herobikes();
  xyz.engine();
  xyz.handle();
  xyz.seat();
  xyz.wheels();
 
  

 }

}

Comment: Error: Main method not found in class abcd.Bikes, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: I have declared the main method....but it is saying that no main method is found..can you pls help

Comment: Please refer this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339088/main-method-not-found-even-if-ive-declared-it

Comment: please provide an answer, this should be a comment